vuetify v-text-field show formated value
I am trying to build a component based on the v-text-field from vuetify and https://github.com/rafaelkendrik/imask-vuetify/blob/master/components/html/ImaskField.vue to displaying an amount in german locale.
<template>
  <v-container class="pa-0" v-if="$attrs.editable">
    <v-text-field
      ref="field"
      :model-value="masked.value"
      @input="input"
      @blur="(event)=> {console.log( event.target.value,'blur');this.checkNormalize();$emit('update:modelValue', Number(this.masked.unmaskedValue))}"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      density="compact"
      variant="outlined"
      @update:model-value="() =>$emit('update:modelValue', this.masked.unmaskedValue)"
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-container>
  <v-container class="pa-0" v-else>
    {{
    betrag === undefined ? "" : betrag.toLocaleString('de-DE', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
    })
    }}
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Imask from 'imask'

const INPUT_EVENT = 'input'

export default {
  name: 'ImaskField',
  components: {BetragsFeld},

  model: {
    prop: 'value',
    event: INPUT_EVENT
  },

  props: {
    betrag: {
      type: [String, Number],
      required: false,
      default: 0
    },
  },

  data: () => ({
    element: {},
    masked: {},
  }),
  watch: {
    betrag : function(val) {
      this.masked.unmaskedValue = '' + val;
      console.log(this.masked.value, "watch")
    },
    masked : function(val) {
      console.log(val, "watch")
    }

  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      this.element = this.$refs.field.$el.querySelector('input')
      this.masked = Imask(this.element, {
        mask: Number,
        thousandsSeparator: '.',
        scale: 2,
        padFractionalZeros: true,  // if true, then pads zeros at end to the length of scale
        normalizeZeros: true,  // appends or removes zeros at ends
        radix: ',',
      })
      this.masked.unmaskedValue=''+this.betrag;
      console.log(this.masked.value, "init")
    },

    input(value) {
      console.log(this.masked.value, "input")
      this.$emit(INPUT_EVENT, value)
    },

    checkNormalize() {
     const isNormalized = (this.element.value === this.masked.value)

      if (!isNormalized) {
        this.element.value = this.masked.value
        this.element.dispatchEvent(new Event(INPUT_EVENT))
      }
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    if (this.$attrs.editable)
      this.init()
  }
}
</script>

if I enter a number, the code shown the correct formatted value, but if I leave the field, the previous value is rendered. anyone has an idea why

By experience, I know that masking is a tough subject. I think that is because it is hard to rely on various interface implementations.
I work on a +3 years Vue application with Vuetify, and we struggled with this. We used to use v-mask library, but we had problems with vuetify inputs and even with native ones. Also, the library is no longer maintained.
I feel like this is a very similar case.
I recommend you to use Maska: https://github.com/beholdr/maska
Works perfectly with Vuetify and native inputs, easy to use api with a lot of options, and it's maintained.

But this library has problem with locale like german https://github.com/beholdr/maska/issues/225. So switching to this lib is not an option
